# Ubuntu 21.04 can't start any program which hasn't been started recently after (maybe) random time

Tags: crash, macbook-air, 21.04, zram, bfq

My MacBook Air running Ubuntu 21.04 is now faster than the 20.04 LTS that I had before. I fixed the secure-boot shimx error, but now the laptop can't start programs which haven't been started recently. I suspect it may be related to how hot the MacBook is getting.

The terminal works, but if I write a command (such as `poweroff`) then press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it doesn't show the prompt anymore and there is no error message. I have to close the terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

The processes keep running except no internet connection (so says Firefox) and the Gnome System Monitor gets stuck. CPU and RAM is normal. I don't know what is happening because programs like htop don't work anymore -- I can't start them. Nothing happens if I try to switch runlevels. I can't close (and kill) Gnome System Monitor, the pop-up appears:

> Gnome system monitor doesn't react anymore

Nothing happens if I press [End Process](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/kill-programs-check-system-information-linux/). The window just appears again if I click on the Gnome System Monitor that keeps getting stuck.

Once I had shut down the laptop doing the following: "open snapd store, the new ubuntu software, go to updates, top right of the three *option bars?*, then I saw "download and restart" and clicked on it. The computer started reboot then".

However rebooting didn't work, the computer waited 12 mins for some processes, then increased the limit if it was until kill, but 12 mins was max. Then it said "target reboot reached", then it waited a long time until the started processes like gnome-software, sudo and poweroff closed -- which didn't happen. Then I tried remounting / to ro (read only), but failed. From there it kept getting stuck and I had to force power off on the laptop.

I have installed following which may be potential causes, these are just some not all:

```
preload, tlp (I didn't start it), cprufreq and this script::

    modprobe bfq
for d in /sys/block/sd?
do
        # HDD (tuned for Seagate SMR drive)
        echo bfq > "$d/queue/scheduler"
        echo 4 > "$d/queue/nr_requests"
        echo 32000 > "$d/queue/iosched/back_seek_max"
        echo 3 > "$d/queue/iosched/back_seek_penalty"
        echo 80 > "$d/queue/iosched/fifo_expire_sync"
        echo 1000 > "$d/queue/iosched/fifo_expire_async"
        echo 5300 > "$d/queue/iosched/slice_idle_us"
        echo 1 > "$d/queue/iosched/low_latency"
        echo 200 > "$d/queue/iosched/timeout_sync"
        echo 0 > "$d/queue/iosched/max_budget"
        echo 1 > "$d/queue/iosched/strict_guarantees"

        # additional tweaks for SSD (tuned for Samsung EVO 850):
        if test $(cat "$d/queue/rotational") = "0"
        then
                echo 36 > "$d/queue/nr_requests"
                echo 1 > "$d/queue/iosched/back_seek_penalty"
                # slice_idle_us should be ~ 0.7/IOPS in µs
                echo 16 > "$d/queue/iosched/slice_idle_us"
                echo 10 > "$d/queue/iosched/fifo_expire_sync"
                echo 250 > "$d/queue/iosched/fifo_expire_async"
                echo 10 > "$d/queue/iosched/timeout_sync"
                echo 0 > "$d/queue/iosched/strict_guarantees"
        fi
done

echo 40 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
echo 90 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio
#echo 50 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
bash speed-performance.sh
```

Speed performance starts tlp in auto mode.

Last time I didn't run this script and the computer just froze, so it isn't the script, but maybe bfq?

PS: CPUFreq says every start my laptop is on Schedutil, now I have set it in German to Bedarf, it's like normal. This time it didn't hang for 1.5 hours, maybe this is the problem. There is no frequency setting in CPUFreq.

Also maybe the laptop has to generate heat to reproduce the fault.

PS: The laptop was normal temperature, and I set performance to "bedarf" and it crashed. What is the problem? Once I had that problem on a WHY! laptop: stand-by, removed ethernet cable but ssh process was running, after I opened the lid it froze. I fixed it, but I don't know how that worked. Here I have an ssh process running, but the cable was on every time.

Comment: command suspend also doesn't work anymore. ctrl c doesn't work but closing terminal works
systemctl suspend (with sudo/root) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was zramswap.
Did it swapped the kernel or what?????

So it didn't crashed now, but I'll look if it does two more times.
Just remember to execute that: `sudo zramswap stop` and then `sudo apt remove zram-tools`
Then zramswap isn't installed anymore

Comment: Now zramswap works on 20.10... Same device